# While scrolling recyclerview in fragment

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

While scrolling recyclerview in fragment, after some content being scrolled app slows down and keep sending this exception to log on single scroll. i am pasting my log exception here.

```
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:501)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:316)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushBytesLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:336)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:359)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flush(FastPrintWriter.java:394)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.dumpGfxInfo(WindowManagerGlobal.java:584)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpGfxInfo(ActivityThread.java:1158)
    at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:576)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
    at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:273)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:319)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:496)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:316) 
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushBytesLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:336) 
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:359) 
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flush(FastPrintWriter.java:394) 
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.dumpGfxInfo(WindowManagerGlobal.java:584) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpGfxInfo(ActivityThread.java:1158) 
    at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:576) 
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

Comment: What about your code, Mind sharing that too? Specifically your adapter

Comment: The exception part of the stacktrace is missing.

Comment: @lukegv this is the whole stack

Comment: @MehmetKologlu sometime this warning doesn't appear, but i ddint anything regarding writing data